# Why Datastore Export API does not support Nearline storage types?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

We have recently configured automated Datastore exports to the Cloud Storage using the new [Datastore Export API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities).

It was obvious that we'd like to use `Nearline` buckets to store our backups, but when we have tried to export the Datastore database to the nearline bucket we received the following error:

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 BAD_REQUEST
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Bucket xxx-xxx-xxx has storage class NEARLINE which is not supported. Must be one of regional, multi_regional, standard, durable_reduced_availability.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Bucket xxx-xxx-xxx has storage class NEARLINE which is not supported. Must be one of regional, multi_regional, standard, durable_reduced_availability.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I haven't found anything in the docs, regarding the Cloud Storage bucket type that should be used.

Is it a documentation or service bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct behaviour. Nearline and Coldline are not supported because of the way that the export writes to GCS.

You can export to standard and then [change](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/changing-storage-classes) to nearline after. You can even automate this with a [SetStorageClass lifecycle action](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle).